# table interpolation

Tags: interpolation

Im looking for advice for efficient way to interpolate data from table like this

```
{{430, {70, 110, 160, 220}, {41, 53, 70, 92}}, {580, {70, 110, 160, 220}, {51, 69, 95, 122}}, {680, {160}, {111}}} // TableForm
```

there are three *records* (rows, 430,580 and 680) and this is X. For evey X, there are one or more Ys, in this case for X 430 there are four Ys(70,110,160,220), the assigned values Z for X-Y pairs are third element in every *record*, in this case for X,Y (430,110) pair teh Z value is 53.
So I'm looking for eficient way to interpolate for between X,Y pairs for Z.

Third *record* have only one Y value, and it will be nice to find way to interpolate for it also.

Comment: What exactly do you want to interpolate, what should the function look like?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to give a proper answer without knowing the exact problem. Nevertheless ...

First, try to write your data in this format (explicitly write x,y,z)

> {{x,y,z,{a1,a2,a3,...}}

Now let's say you have `n` number of `a`'s (`a1,...,an`)

```
n=3
data = {{x1, y1, z1, {a1, a2, a3}}, {x2, y2, z2, {b1, b2, b3}}}
f[x_,y_,z_]= Table[Interpolate[Join[#[[1 ;; 3]], {#[[4, i]]}] & /@ data][x,y,z],{i,n}]
```